# F# List optimisation

Tags: performance, f#

From an unordered list of int, I want to have the smallest difference between two elements. I have a code that is working but way to slow. Can anyone sugest some change to improve the performance? Please explain **why** you did the change and what will be the performance gain.

```
let allInt = [ 5; 8; 9 ]

let sortedList = allInt |> List.sort;

let differenceList = [ for a in 0 .. N-2 do yield sortedList.Item a - sortedList.Item a + 1 ]

printfn "%i" (List.min differenceList) // print 1 (because 9-8 smallest difference)
```

I think I'm doing to much list creation or iteration but I don't know how to write it differently in F#...yet.

**Edit:** I'm testing this code on list with 100 000 items or more.

**Edit 2:** I believe that if I can calculte the difference and have the min in one go it should improve the perf a lot, but I don't know how to do that, anay idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick comment before I post an answer to your "Edit 2" question: you've used commas between your list items, but in F# you should use semicolons. Your `allInt` list should be written as `[ 5; 8; 9]`.

Comment: If you use commas in a list, that's valid syntax, but it doesn't produce what you probably think it will produce. Commas in F# **always** define a tuple, and the parentheses around a tuple definition are **optional**. So `[5, 8, 9]` is actually a list of *one* item, and that item is a *tuple of 3 ints*. This syntax comes in handy when you want a list of key-value pairs, because you can write it `[key1, value1; key2, value2; key3, value3]`. But it creates a subtle trap for F# beginners who are used to languages like C#. Remember that in F#, **comma means tuple** and you should be fine.

Comment: sorry about the comma, In fact i got the list from another function that is not important here. (read then slip, I made this as an example). I'll change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The List.Item performs in O(n) time and is probably the main performance bottle neck in your code. The evaluation of `differenceList` iterates the elements of `sortedList` by index, which means the performance is around O((N-2)*(2*(N-2))), which simplifies to O(N^2), where N is the number of elements in `sortedList`. For long lists, this will eventually perform badly.

What I would do is to eliminate calls to Item and instead use the List.pairwise operation

```
let data =
    [ let rnd = System.Random()
      for i in 1..100000 do yield rnd.Next() ]

#time

let result =
    data
    |> List.sort
    |> List.pairwise     // convert list from [a;b;c;...] to [(a,b); (b,c); ...]
    |> List.map (fun (a,b) -> a - b |> abs)  // Calculates the absolute difference
    |> List.min

#time
```

The #time directives lets me measure execution time in F# Interactive and the output I get when running this code is:

```
--> Timing now on

Real: 00:00:00.029, CPU: 00:00:00.031, GC gen0: 1, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
val result : int = 0

--> Timing now off
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I liked that you gave the complexity and some timing. (You just teach me how to do it now :D). Very clear and concise solution.

Comment: Your function will *always* return zero. You need one more line of code filtering out the diagonal pairs, i.e, the pairs where `a = b`.

Comment: Also, I believe you need to call allPairs, not pairwise.

Comment: First, the function will *not* always return zero, but it happens to be the case many times due to duplicates in `data`. I verified this. Adding List.distinct and/or reducing the list size to e.g. 1000 elements, will start showing more illustrative results.

Second, when the list is sorted, List.pairwise will suffice because the elements numerically closest will be next to each other in the list.

Comment: @Matiasd - You are right that the function will not always return zero. It would if you had used allPairs instead of pairwise.

Answer (score 7):

F#'s built-in list type is implemented as a linked list, which means accessing elements by index has to enumerate the list all the way to the index each time. In your case you have two index accesses repeated N-2 times, getting slower and slower with each iteration, as the index grows and each access needs to go through longer part of the list.

First way out of this would be using an array instead of a list, which is a trivial change, but grants you faster index access.

```
(*
    [| and |] let you define an array literal,
    alternatively use List.toArray allInt
*)
let allInt = [| 5; 8; 9 |] 
let sortedArray = allInt |> Array.sort;
let differenceList = [ for a in 0 .. N-2 do yield sortedArray.[a] - sortedArray.[a + 1] ]
```

Another approach might be pairing up the neighbours in the list, subtracting them and then finding a min.

```
let differenceList =
    sortedList
    |> List.pairwise
    |> List.map (fun (x,y) -> x - y)
```

`List.pairwise` takes a list of elements and returns a list of the neighbouring pairs. E.g. in your example `List.pairwise [ 5; 8; 9 ] = [ (5, 8); (8, 9) ]`, so that you can easily work with the pairs in the next step, the subtraction mapping.

This way is better, but these functions from List module take a list as input and produce a new list as the output, having to pass through the list 3 times (1 for `pairwise`, 1 for `map`, 1 for `min` at the end). To solve this, you can use functions from the `Seq` module, which work with .NETs `IEnumerable<'a>` interface allowing lazy evaluation resulting usually in fewer passes.

Fortunately in this case `Seq` defines alternatives for all the functions we use here, so the next step is trivial:

```
let differenceSeq =
    sortedList
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.map (fun (x,y) -> x - y)

let minDiff = Seq.min differenceSeq
```

This should need only one enumeration of the list (excluding the sorting phase of course).

But I cannot guarantee you which approach will be fastest. My bet would be on simply using an array instead of the list, but to find out, you will have to try it out and measure for yourself, on your data and your hardware. [BehchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) library can help you with that.

Comment: A benchmarking framework is overkill for this. You can tell a lot just by quick timing of code with FSI and `#time`. As another answer mentions, most of the time is taken by list `.Item`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it's clear and I learn new things about the nitty gritty details of F#

Answer (score 4):

The rest of your question is adequately covered by the other answers, so I won't duplicate them. But nobody has yet addressed the question you asked in your **Edit 2**. To answer that question, if you're doing a calculation and then want the minimum result of that calculation, you want `List.minBy`. One clue that you want `List.minBy` is when you find yourself doing a `map` followed by a `min` operation (as both the other answers are doing): that's a classic sign that you want `minBy`, which does that in one operation instead of two.

There's one gotcha to watch out for when using `List.minBy`: It returns the *original* value, not the *result* of the calculation. I.e., if you do `ints |> List.pairwise |> List.minBy (fun (a,b) -> abs (a - b))`, then what `List.minBy` is going to return is a *pair* of items, not the difference. It's written that way because if it gives you the original value but you really wanted the result, you can always recalculate the result; but if it gave you the result and you really wanted the original value, you might not be able to get it. (Was that difference of 1 the difference between 8 and 9, or between 4 and 5?)

So in your case, you could do:

```
let allInt = [5; 8; 9]
let minPair =
    allInt
    |> List.pairwise
    |> List.minBy (fun (x,y) -> abs (x - y))
let a, b = minPair
let minDifference = abs (a - b)
printfn "The difference between %d and %d was %d" a b minDifference
```

The `List.minBy` operation also exists on sequences, so if your list is large enough that you want to avoid creating an intermediate list of pairs, then use `Seq.pairwise` and `Seq.minBy` instead:

```
let allInt = [5; 8; 9]
let minPair =
    allInt
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.minBy (fun (x,y) -> abs (x - y))
let a, b = minPair
let minDifference = abs (a - b)
printfn "The difference between %d and %d was %d" a b minDifference
```

**EDIT:** Yes, I see that you've got a list of 100,000 items. So you definitely want the `Seq` version of this. The F# `seq` type is just `IEnumerable`, so if you're used to C#, think of the `Seq` functions as LINQ expressions and you'll have the right idea.

P.S. One thing to note here: see how I'm doing `let a, b = minPair`? That's called *destructuring assignment*, and it's really useful. I could also have done this:

```
let a, b =
    allInt
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.minBy (fun (x,y) -> abs (x - y))
```

and it would have given me the same result. `Seq.minBy` returns a tuple of two integers, and the `let a, b = (tuple of two integers)` expression takes that tuple, matches it against the pattern `a, b`, and thus assigns `a` to have the value of that tuple's first item, and `b` to have the value of that tuple's second item. Notice how I used the phrase "matches it against the pattern": this is the *exact same thing* as when you use a `match` expression. Explaining match expressions would make this answer too long, so I'll just point you to an excellent reference on them if you haven't already read it:

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and detailled explaination, that really help me, and I'm now looking into the doc about keywords you talk about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
let minPair xs =
    let foo (x, y) = abs (x - y)
    xs
    |> List.allPairs xs
    |> List.filter (fun (x, y) -> x <> y)
    |> List.minBy foo
    |> foo
```

Comment: This solution fails to address the performance issue, since `xs |> List.allPairs xs` will result in a list of n^2 elements. Also, it disallows duplicate elements, which is a breaking change from the original implementation.